# Creating a Dataframe from another Dataframe and using DatetimeIndex fills columns with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Prod":  [10, 20],
        "Sales":    [1, 4],
        "DT":       ["2021-05-01 15:05:01", "2021-05-01 15:05:05"]
    },
    index=None
)

  Prod  Sales   DT
0   10    1     2021-05-01 15:05:01
1   20    4     2021-05-01 15:05:05
```

OK so now I create a new dataframe just using the 'Prod' column and 'DT' for the index.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    df1["Prod"],
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(df1["DT"])
)

                   Prod
DT  
2021-05-01 15:05:01 NaN
2021-05-01 15:05:05 NaN
```

Values for 'Prod' have not been picked up and I need to convert the 'Prod' column to a list first.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    list(df1["Prod"]),
    columns=["Prod"],
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(df1["DT"])
)

                   Prod
DT  
2021-05-01 15:05:01 10
2021-05-01 15:05:05 20
```

So what is the problem with the original code? I would have thought Pandas would have thrown an error if it was unhappy.

Comment: it fails, because Pandas aligns on the index before any computation; if you dont want that alignment, then the `list` option is right, or you could just access the data beneath with `df1.Prod.array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `df1['Prod']` is a pandas Series with its own index (`0`, `1`). When you specified a new index with `index=pd.DatetimeIndex(df1["DT"]`, the old and the new indexes do not line up. Hence you got `NaN`.

The solution is simple:

```py
df2 = df1[['Prod', 'DT']].set_index('DT')
```